# Get location from user and perform an external request in api.ai

Tags: machine-learning, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot

Can someone show me using the code
used in the course to get a location from the user(current or any other)
and then use it to show Google map with banks or schools api.ai?

Comment: I am using facebook messenger

Answer (score 0):

You can trace user location without Google maps. Use geolocation API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Geolocation API supports all latest browser including mobile devices.

You can get the user's current location as given below,

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});
```

Within the callback, you can make an external AJAX request to send this information to the remote server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I omitted something in the question. I am doing this in the api.ai machine learning platform.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about that bro.

Comment: No problem. Thanks.